# Entity Framework I could not create the linq query

Tags: sql, entity-framework, linq

This is my scenario for tables

Users can transfer money to each others. There are two options when the transferring. One is the direct to users budget, other one is project budget for the user to spend.

```
|- TransferTable -|              |- ProjectEnum.cs -|      |- TransferProjectTable -|
  |TransferId|                      |Budget|                   |TransferProjectId|
  |senderAccountId|                 |Project|                  |TransferId|
  |recipientAccountId|                                         |ProjectId|
  |ProjectEnum|
  |Date|
  |Amount|
  |SenderUserId|

|- AccountTable - |          |- ProjectTable -|
   |AccountId|                  |ProjectId|
   |BankName|                   |Name|
   |UserId|
   |IBAN|
```

a user can have multiple bank accounts. So, I would like to see list for transfer table according to recipter account Id. This means, To list transfers to all accounts of the user.

If transfer to project, It will be return project name.

It have to return that class

```
TransferListDto.cs
TransferId
SenderAccountId
ReciptientAccountId
ProjectEnum
ProjectId // If not any, it will be null val
ProjectName // if not any, it will be null val
Date
Amount
SenderUserId
```

I try this code but I got stuck, It empty list is returning.

```
            var result = (from h in context.Accounts
                          join t in context.Transfers on h.AccountId equals t.RecipientAccountId
                          join tp in context.TransferProjects on t.TransferId equals tp.TransferId
                          join u in context.Users on h.UserId equals u.Id
                          join p in context.Projects on tp.ProjeId equals p.ProjeId
                          where h.UserId == userId
                          select new TransferListDto()
                          {
                              TransferId = t.TransferId,
                              UserId = u.Id,
                              NameSurname = u.Name + " " + u.Surname,
                              RecipientAccountId = t.RecipientAccountId,
                              SenderAccountId = t.SenderAccountId ,
                              ProjectEnum = t.ProjectEnum,
                              ProjeId = tp.ProjeId,
                              ProjeName = p.Name,
                              Date = t.Date,
                              Amount = t.Amount,

                          }).ToList();

            return result;
```

Comment: Use navigation properties, not `join`. EF will figure out the type of join that's appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`join` will perform inner join, so if there is no `Transfer` or `TransferProjects` you will get empty list. You need to perform [left outer join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-left-outer-joins). Something like this (not sure that it will compile, but you should get the gist of it):

```
var result = (from h in context.Accounts
                      join tl in context.Transfers on h.HesapId equals tl.RecipientAccountId into tlG
                      from t in tlG.DefaultIfEmpty()
                      join tpl in context.TransferProjects on t.TransferId equals tpl.TransferId into tplG
                      from tp in tplG.DefaultIfEmpty()
                      join u in context.Users on h.UserId equals u.Id
                      join pl in context.Projects on tp.ProjeId equals pl.ProjeId into plG
                      from p in plG.DefaultIfEmpty()
                      where h.UserId == userId
                      select new TransferListDto()
                      {
                          TransferId = t.TransferId,
                          UserId = u.Id,
                          NameSurname = u.Name + " " + u.Surname,
                          RecipientAccountId = t.RecipientAccountId,
                          SenderAccountId = t.SenderAccountId ,
                          ProjectEnum = t.ProjectEnum,
                          ProjeId = tp.ProjeId,
                          ProjeName = p.Name,
                          Date = t.Date,
                          Amount = t.Amount,

                      }).ToList();
```